# Attempting to send POST request to URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I'm trying to post to a webserver in iOS but am receiving a 404 error. The person I'm working with is able to post from a different system with the address and data in a single string:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/message?salu=mr&firstname=john&lastname=smith&email=smith@testemail.com&country=usa&zipcode=99999&checkbox=y&messagelist=message&q1=1&q2=2&q3=3&q4=4&q5=5

I'm trying to do the same with the following code in Xcode:

```
 NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message?salu=mr&firstname=john&lastname=smith&email=matt@testmail.com&country=usa&zipcode=99999&checkbox=y&messagelist=message&q1=1&q2=2&q3=3&q4=4&q5=5"];

 NSData *data = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api"]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody:data];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *err;
 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
 NSString *reply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", reply);
```

and the last few lines of 'reply' above from NSLog are:

```
<b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
        <br><br>

        <b> Requested URL: </b>/api<br><br>

</body>
```

However, I'm able to perform a 'GET' on the same address with the following code, where I receive the expected data:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
 [request2 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/message"]];
 [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

 NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
 NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

 NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

So the web server is functioning and it appears the problem lies in the way I'm posting. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but you generally should avoid `sendSynchronousRequest`. Use asynchronous requests. Also, while you've hard-coded the body for the purpose of this test, when you start building that body more dynamically, don't forget to do the necessary percent escaping (e.g. as outlined in point #1 of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26153527/1271826)). Or use a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) that takes care of these sorts of details for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll remember to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api"]];
```

Don't you notice that you should call `NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/message"]];`

/message is part of path, not request body.

and look forward to use some ready framework, such as AFNetworking is.

Comment: Hi, yeah I fiddled with this earlier, but when I include 'message' as part of the path I get the message 'No HTTP resource found ...

Answer (score 1):

You've taken the last path component of the request's URL, `message`, and put that into the body of the request. So, replace:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api"]];
```

with

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/message"]];
```

Also, replace:

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message?salu=mr&firstname=john&lastname=smith&email=matt@testmail.com&country=usa&zipcode=99999&checkbox=y&messagelist=message&q1=1&q2=2&q3=3&q4=4&q5=5"];
```

with:

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"salu=mr&firstname=john&lastname=smith&email=matt@testmail.com&country=usa&zipcode=99999&checkbox=y&messagelist=message&q1=1&q2=2&q3=3&q4=4&q5=5"];
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but then I get the error  'No HTTP resource found ...', wheras it recognizes the address without it.

Comment: Please update your question with the full `NSLog` of the `NSURLResponse` object (which is really a `NSHTTPURLResponse` object). It's hard to diagnose the problem remotely when we only have snippets of messages, rather than the full `NSURLResponse` object. Setting that aside, I might next suggest you watch both the `POST` and `GET` attempts via something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and make sure the URLs are the same and that your `POST` rendition does not have the `?` anywhere in it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I looked in Charles and both addresses show up the same for both the POST and GET, where its given as: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/message. With the POST i get a 404 error, but the GET works fine. I'm really baffled why the address is not recognized on the POST but is on the GET.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and help. I got it to work only by including the data in with the url upon initializing the request, like so:

     ... *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL     
     URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/message? 
salu=mr&firstname=Jason...

Thus I can't send the data in the body. Perhaps it has something to do with the encoding.

Comment: It's not ideal to include it in the URL because (a) it's limited in length (and I don't know what you have in the "message"; could it be long); and (b) assuming your production app uses https, including stuff in the URL isn't very secure (as it tends to appear in random server logs, etc.). Re encoding suspicion, the 404 is a more fundamental error than that, so I'd really doubt it. Yes, you should should be percent escaping, but that wouldn't be a problem unless you had non alphanumeric characters in any of those values. And it wouldn't manifest itself as 404, methinks.

Comment: I think the problem was the websever didn't recognize the encoding of the data (its a crude and primitive internal server). Is there a way to send NSData as plain text?

Comment: If the server didn't recognize the data, it wouldn't be a 404. And your `NSASCIIStringEncoded` will give you plain text. Generally, though, you'd do [percent escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069977/send-post-data-to-php-file-from-ios/26153527#26153527) of the values rather than doing a lossy conversion.